# Force user to lock file in SVN before editing

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

We have some files in our project that can't be merged and hence the files must be locked by the users before editing them. Is there a way to force the user to lock a file before editing?

We are using Subversion and TortoiseSVN / VisualSVN.

Comment: As others have stated, you can use the `svn:needs-lock` property on those files. You can use a pre-commit hook to require that these files have locks. You can also install a pre-unlock hook to prevent users from stealing locks. Usually, this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Two steps:

- put the **svn:needs-lock** property on those files. That way they are check out read-only
- when such a file must be modified, use the **svn lock** command and commit as usual

links:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html
- http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html

Answer (score 18):

More specifically, if you have TortoiseSVN installed,

1. Right-click the file in Windows Explorer, select TortoiseSVN->Properties
2. Click New->NeedsLock
3. Choose Locking required in the dialog: [image]
4. Click OK
5. Commit the file
6. Done!