# Using Subversion with XCode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have little experience using VSS before. For iOS development, I have installed Subversion on a remote Windows machine and accessing it from my Mac. And I have a few gray areas to clear up.

1. [This](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/version-control-is-your-friend.html) is one of the tutorials I followed. But its written based
   on an older version of XCode. The SCM tab in XCode preferences is
   not in XCode 4.6. Is it completely removed or moved somewhere else?
2. The main reason to choose Subversion over Git was the ability to
   lock files in Subversion. I know you can do it through the Terminal.
   Is there a way to do it through XCode itself?
3. Say I checkout an XCode project to my local mac. And locked a
   certain file. An another co-worker also checkout the same project to
   edit that same file I locked. I read that the other person can also
   edit that file but he cannot commit it back since it is locked. Is there a way to
   notify the other people that a certain file is locked at the time of
   checking out?
4. In the repository, I have created the standard tags, branches and
   trunk folders. The project should be in trunk folder, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the menu bar, choose Window > Organizer.  Then in the Organizer window, choose the Repositories tab.  The + button at the bottom left lets you add a new repository.
2. No.
3. [You could try setting the `svn:needs-lock` property, I suppose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569948/force-user-to-lock-file-in-svn-before-editing), but you won't be able to do that from Xcode.
4. Yes.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the response. I can use something like TortiseSVN to set the `svn:needs-lock`, right? Soo I should first checkout the project, set this property for files I need to lock from the server afterwards so that the next person who checkout only will get the read-only access, am I right?

Comment: I don't know anything about TortoiseSVN or what properties it might be able to set.