# How to block editing SVN file from two locations at the same time

Tags: svn

Is there a way to set editing a SVN document from one location at a time? I mean, if someone is editing a particular file, others cannot edit that file till he commits it or rollback to last stable state. Bottom line is I want to avoid SVN file conflicts and save the time that we use to resolving conflicts.

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569948/force-user-to-lock-file-in-svn-before-editing

Comment: You may drastically reduce conflict resolution time, but more likely you're going to introduce 15 seconds of unlocking someone elses lock before committing.  If you elect to forbid this with a hook, you're going to introduce a bunch of waiting for someone to unlock (or waiting for the admin to unlock it).   Locking isn't the path - deal with any conflicts, the team will be happier and faster.

Comment: Sometimes you just need the lock - conflicts aren't necessarily problems with merging (I blame the devs for having a branch that's too long-lived or too many changes for that), sometimes conflicts are having to rework changes to a binary image or similar. Communication is easier, but that depends on many factors. If he needs locking, let's not make assumptions what his problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the needs-lock property you can set on files. Read up on [locking in the redbook.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html)