# Individual file checkouts in the latest version of Apache Subversion 1.8.8

Tags: svn

Can we do individual file checkouts in the latest version of Apache Subversion 1.8.8.. Is there a locking functionality for individual files in the latest version. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

svn has had file locking for a while...

see the answer to this post - [Force user to lock file in SVN before editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569948/force-user-to-lock-file-in-svn-before-editing)

svn also allows you to checkout a subset of the files in any path, called sparse checkout

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html

Comment: Thank you bkr for the information. With the individual file checkouts called  sparse checkouts can be done only on cammand line right. we could not do it from the actual repository

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...

You can use a tool like TortoiseSVN ( see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html ) assuming you're on windows if you want a GUI interface, but I get the feeling I'm missing what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Checking out single file is possible .
Through command line:

1. First checkout the parent directory with --depth empty
2. Update the directory with the file you want.

Please refer the link

[Checkout one file from Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion)

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=823

Locking of file is also possible in SVN .

Hope this helps

Regards

Jyotsna